# Inventory data not updating

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have product variant ex. variant1 . Now when I try to update the name to "variant12" the name gets updated in Merchandizing manager but the same change is not reflecting in inventory. I am working on Sitecore commerce 9.0.2

Do I have to rebuild any index?

Comment: you mean SellableItem Name or DisplayName?

Comment: @AndreiPaliakou Display name

Comment: When you say you changed the name, you mean the variant id? If that's the case the relationship will be broken i believe because the inventory was associated to the old Id. You will most likely need to re-associate the inventory to the new named variant.
If you check the variant in BizFx do you see the inventory still associated? (Last view in the bottom of the variant page)

Comment: I have not changed any id. I have changed the name of the product variant in Merchandizing manager. Now as the product variant is associated in inventory, this name change should reflect in inventory also but it is not reflecting

Comment: I think what happens is there are two properties Name and Display name. Name is what's used in Inventory but what you changed is DisplayName. Name is not editable out of the box in Bizfx. If you really need to change the name you can extend the variant details view to display the name as well.

Comment: @YassineAlahyane Is there any other way to edit the name, through postman?

Comment: Just noticed that the name is not getting updated for product variant items which have special characters like " ( / " .